# Why do I get this compile error when calculating arithmetic in C? Error C2143 missing ':' before type

Tags: c

In the following code visual studio gives me this error: `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'`.
 I'm not really sure why. I am new to C language.

```
double areac1 = L1*W1;      //area of ceiling in first room
double areatotalc1 = L1*W1*2; //area of ceiling in first room to be painted

double gallonsexactc1 = areatotalc/ 350;    //area covered by one gallon in first room
double gallonsboughtc1 = ceil(gallonsexactc1);  //number of gallons bought for first room 

double costpaintc1 = gallonsboughtc1*27.98;     //cost to paint the ceiling in first room
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error? What are `L1` and `W1`?

Comment: you are probably missing a semicolon in the statement right above your first statement shown here `double areac1 = L1*W1;`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have defined L1 and W1 before use in your code . Your code would work fine if you replace

```
double gallonsexactc1 = areatotalc/ 350;
```

with

```
double gallonsexactc1 = areatotalc1/ 350;
```

as you have not defined `areatotalc` its `areatotalc1`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is:
         `double gallonsexactc1 = areatotalc/ 350;`

Correct Way:
You just declare L1 & W1 and make correction in your code like this..
        `double gallonsexactc1 = areatotalc1/ 350;`
This will probably solve your problem

Comment: This answer really doesn't make any sense.